# PhoneGap loading external mobile web app and Apple Reject?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to write my web mobile app and share it on markets like the app store and android market, but I want all users to be able to view my web app browsing at http://mywebapp.com/m/

I decided to use PhoneGap and jQueryMobile with getJSON method and append the parsing data to the DOM of my page. 
But this technique generates a lot of javascript files with ajax calls and json parsing.

Another technique could be to call changePage (jqueryMobile api) and point PhoneGap to my website (which has pages generated server side, no getJSON at all!):

```
    $.mobile.changePage("http://mywebapp.com/m/");
```

Can Apple reject this method, and can you suggest another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think a lot on this and i understand that the risk Apple can reject is too high, because apple has not any control over webapp's remote changes.

I decide to add backbone.js along with phonegap and write a full client using a MVC pattern which make code clean and elegant and also fetch and parse data from server in a better way using model and templates.

I hope this can help someone on this doubt.

Lorenzo